# Google Map cutting off

Tags: javascript, css, google-maps

Can someone please help me with why the Google Map I have setup under "Project Portfolio" cuts itself off when you move around the map?

```
<div id="map-canvas" style="width: 100%; height: 500px;"></div>

var mapOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(45.398621, -75.737116),
      zoom: 14,
      scrollwheel: false,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);
```

Comment: It's because you have something like 8 console errors which is stopping your javascript execution.

Comment: Might help to show all of your code because there are 8 errors including a Google Maps API error showing up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the page loads, your javascript stops working because of errors.

The consequence of it is that the code supposed to retrieve map data is not executed.

By the way, you can read the following error :

> You have included the Google Maps API multiple times on this page.
>   This may cause unexpected errors.

You might want to fix that.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it.